# return value of update statement in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-update

what kind of value does a update statement in sql lite return when invoked via java? is it boolean?

i'm trying to update a few rows and want to fetch whether it worked correctly or threw exceptions.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1)
The method where you are executing the update query:

```
public boolean updateTable() {

  boolean isSuccessFul = false;
  // Prepare the statements and the connections

  try {
    // Execute the update

    isSuccessFul = true;
  } catch(Exception e) {
    // Handle it
  } finally {
     return isSuccessFul;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the sentence with iOS you get the number of rows modified, I think in Java will be similar

Answer (score 1):

**int executeUpdate() throws SQLExceptionSQLException**

Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.
**Returns:**
either (1) **the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements** or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing
**Throws:**
SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed PreparedStatement or the SQL statement returns a ResultSet object
       SQLTimeoutException - when the driver has determined that the timeout value that was specified by the setQueryTimeout method has been exceeded and has at least attempted to cancel the currently running Statement